# Altering SQL tables based on condition

Tags: php, mysql, alter-table

Is there any possible way to add a row of data to only some of the tables in a database? I am not sure what parameter I could use amongst the tables to compare them to each other. Any Ideas?
**For Example:**
My database has tables that are (let's say) group A tables, and tables that are group B. I want to add a row to only the group B tables while leaving the group A tables untouched.

---

Sorry I should have been a bit more specific. The tables that need to have a row added will change. My application monitors inventory in different store locations(each table in my database represents a store). When I need to add an item to inventory(the items are rows in the tables) I don't want to have to manually add the row to all the store tables.

My problem is: Not all the tables in the database represent stores. For instance one table stores the user login data. Obviously I do not want to add the new row to this table. How do I update only the tables that represent stores?

Comment: then you just insert into group A, not sure what is your problem still...

Comment: I think you need to be a little more explicit than "Group _ tables". What makes them part of the group? And an INSERT is only going to work on the tables you specify.

Comment: Do I misunderstand? Rows are added to specific tables. If you don't want to update a table, just don't use that table in your update statement.

Comment: do you perhaps mean add a __column__ to a table?

Comment: Post Edit. Explained more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Create two files additem.html, insert.php add the following code to it.

additem.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
item1: <input type="text" name="item1" />
item2: <input type="text" name="item2" />
item3: <input type="text" name="item3" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

file :insert.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","Parker","abc123") or  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());//change the mysql user name and password(Parker,abc123)


mysql_select_db("inventory", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO store (item1, item2,item3)
VALUES ('$_POST[item1]', '$_POST[item2]', '$_POST[item3]')");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks rajmohan, but wouldn't this code only be able to insert the new items into one table in the database? My objective is to identify all of the 'store' tables dynamically and then add them to the query so that when a new item is added, all of the store tables will be updated.